# How to get the "src" attribute from an <iframe> tag posted in a text input field, using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, iframe

Suppose the  tag is an embed link from Google maps:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3025.306387423317!2d-74.04668908414591!3d40.68924937933434!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c25090129c363d%3A0x40c6a5770d25022b!2sStatue+of+Liberty+National+Monument!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1495685672306" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And I paste it onto this text input field with a button:

```
<input type="text" id="embed_link" name="embed_link">

<button class="save_button" data-button="location">Save</button>
```

I could then get the value of the iframe tag using jQuery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".save_button").on('click', function() {
    var embed_link =  $("#embed_link").val();
  });
});
```

How could I then get the "src" attribute from the `embed_link` variable?

Here's what I've tried:

```
var embed_src = embed_link.attr('src'); 
or
var embed_src = $("#embed_link").val().attr('src');

//(doesn't work. I keep getting this error: 
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).val(...).attr is not a function.
It probably has to be an iframe on the page for this to work I guess?)
```

Here's a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b5dkh98x/) for the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".save_button").on('click', function() {
  
    var embed_link =  $($("#embed_link").val()).attr('src');
    //var embed_src = $('#embed_link').val().attr('src');
    
    alert(embed_link); // Works
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="embed_link" name="embed_link">

<button class="save_button" data-button="location">Save</button> 

<!--p>
Iframe test link: 

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3025.306387423317!2d-74.04668908414591!3d40.68924937933434!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c25090129c363d%3A0x40c6a5770d25022b!2sStatue+of+Liberty+National+Monument!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1495685672306" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</p-->
```

you should use `$($("#embed_link").val()).attr('src');`

here is jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/0e5butsh/

you are getting error because your are trying to get src from string.

> $("#embed_link").val() gives you string. you need to convert this string to element and get the src

Comment: Thanks. Accepting the answer for being the first to respond.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `embed_link` as a selector

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".save_button").on('click', function() {      
    var embed_link =  $("#embed_link").val();        
    alert($(embed_link).attr('src')); // Works
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="embed_link" name="embed_link">

<button class="save_button" data-button="location">Save</button> 

<!--p>
Iframe test link: 

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3025.306387423317!2d-74.04668908414591!3d40.68924937933434!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c25090129c363d%3A0x40c6a5770d25022b!2sStatue+of+Liberty+National+Monument!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1495685672306" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</p-->
```

Comment: Thanks for the extra effort of adding a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".save_button").on('click', function() {
  
    var embed_link = $("#embed_link").val();
    
    console.log($(embed_link).attr('src')); // Works
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="embed_link" name="embed_link">

<button class="save_button" data-button="location">Save</button> 

<!--p>
Iframe test link: 

<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3025.306387423317!2d-74.04668908414591!3d40.68924937933434!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c25090129c363d%3A0x40c6a5770d25022b!2sStatue+of+Liberty+National+Monument!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1495685672306" width="800" height="600" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

</p-->
```

1. Change the value of the input into a jquery object by wrapping it in $().
2. use `.attr('src')` to get the src

Comment: Thanks for the snippet and the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".save_button").on('click', function() {

    var embed_link =  $("#embed_link").val();
    //var embed_src = $('#embed_link').val().attr('src');

    console.log($(embed_link)[0].src); 
  });
});
```

Comment: Please try to avoid just dumping code as an answer and try to explain what it does and why. Your code might not be obvious for people who do not have the relevant coding experience.